# Send data by network and plot with octave

Tags: bash, plot, octave

I am working on a robot and my goal is to plot the state of the robot.

For now, my workflow is this:

1. Launch the program
2. Redirect the output in a file (robot/bash): `rosrun explo explo_node > states.txt`
3. Send the file to my local machine (robot/bash): `scp states.txt my_desktop:/home/user`
4. Plot the states with octave (desktop/octave): `plot_data('states.txt')`

Is there a simple solution to have the data in "real time"? For the octave side. I think that I can with not so much difficulty read from a file as an input and plot the data when data is added.

The problem is how do I send the data to a file?

I am opened to other solutions than octave. The thing is that I need to have 2d plot with arrows for the orientation of the robot.

Comment: I think the limitation is this "rosrun/rosbash" thing. If you have `nc` you can open a tcp socket with Octave and use `nc` to send the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of how you could send the data over the network (as Andy suggested) and plot **as it is generated** (i.e. realtime). I also think this approach is the most flexible / appropriate.

To demonstrate, I will use a bash script that generates an

  <sub>[image]</sub>

 pair every 10th of a second, for the

  <sub>[image]</sub>

function, in the range 

  <sub>[image]</sub>
:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# script: sin.sh

for i in `seq 0 0.01 31.4`;
do
  printf "$i, `echo "s($i)" | bc -l`\n"
  sleep 0.1
done
```

<sub>(Don't forget to make this script executable!)</sub>

Prepare the following octave script (requires the [sockets package](https://octave.sourceforge.io/sockets/index.html)!):

```matlab
% in visualiseRobotData.m
pkg load sockets
s = socket();
bind(s, 9000);
listen(s, 1);
c = accept(s);

figure; hold on; 
while ! isempty (a = str2num (char (recv (c, inf))))
  plot (a(:,1), a(:,2), '*'); drawnow;
end
hold off;
```

Now execute things in the following order:

1. Run the `visualiseRobotData` script from the octave terminal.
    <sub>(Note: this will block until a connection is established)</sub>
2. From your bash terminal run: `./sin.sh | nc localhost 9000`

And watch the datapoints get plotted as they come in from your `sin.sh` script.

Comment: nice answer, perhaps we should also add it to the GNU Octave wiki. Btw, I often want a live plot with constant width where new samples are added to the right and old deleted from the left which is easy if setting `ydata` on the generated line.

Comment: @Andy thanks, if you have a suggestion where such an example could go on the wiki, I'd be happy to add it.

Comment: That is the better answer, thank you very much! I have only one problem it is that when the program is stopped, I cannot use the same port again because it saying that is already used. So have to restart octave-cli. Do you know why? (That's not a real problem because I have skirted it...)

Comment: @onda47: without using @ others doesn't get a notification and they typically don't monitor all their posts. It's pure luck that I've seen this because Tasos linked this answer to another question. For your question: You have to use SO_REUSEADDR if you want to use the port again (or wait until timeout). See this fork: https://github.com/octave-de/octave-sockets-enh

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit crude, but you can just reload the file in a loop.  This one runs for 5 minutes:

```
for i = 1:300
  load Test/sine.txt
  plot (sine(:,1), sine(:,2))
  sleep (1)
endfor
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mount remote directory via `sshfs`:

```
sshfs user@remote:/path/to/remote_dir local_dir
```

so you wouldn't have to load remote file. If `sshfs` is not installed, install it. To unmount remote directory later, execute

```
fusermount -u local_dir
```

To get a robot's data from Octave, execute (Octave code)

```
system("ssh user@host 'cd remote_dir; rosrun explo explo_node > states.txt'")
%% then plot picture from the data in local_dir
%% that is defacto the directory on the remote server
```