# How to load real time data in octave

Tags: machine-learning, octave

How can I load real time data in octave?

Here's an example of the data I'm trying to load in octave for analyzing:

```
hpi_type    hpi_flavor  frequency   level   place_name  place_id    yr  period  index_nsa   index_sa
traditional purchase-only   monthly USA or Census Division  East North Central Division DV_ENC  1991    1   100 100
traditional purchase-only   monthly USA or Census Division  East North Central Division DV_ENC  1991    2   101.04  101.12
traditional purchase-only   monthly USA or Census Division  East North Central Division DV_ENC  1991    3   101.4   101.07
traditional purchase-only   monthly USA or Census Division  East North Central Division DV_ENC  1991    4   101.8   101.12
traditional purchase-only   monthly USA or Census Division  East North Central Division DV_ENC  1991    5   102.43  101.5
traditional purchase-only   monthly USA or Census Division  East North Central Division DV_ENC  1991    6   102.85  101.6
traditional purchase-only   monthly USA or Census Division  East North Central Division DV_ENC  1991    7   103.07  102.01
traditional purchase-only   monthly USA or Census Division  East North Central Division DV_ENC  1991    8   103.23  102.22
traditional purchase-only   monthly USA or Census Division  East North Central Division DV_ENC  1991    9   102.92  102.12
traditional purchase-only   monthly USA or Census Division  East North Central Division DV_ENC  1991    10  103.17  102.51
traditional purchase-only   monthly USA or Census Division  East North Central Division DV_ENC  1991    11  104.05  103.44
traditional purchase-only   monthly USA or Census Division  East North Central Division DV_ENC  1991    12  103.81  103.54
```

Comment: If you want to "load" your data from an image you have to do OCR (Optical character recognition) which isn't a task which should be done in Octave. If you just thought you make a screenshot of your data in some sort of viewer and you don't think it's important that we know the file format, you should rethink it this is feasible.

Comment: 1) your data as text was good, you only had to prepend four blanks to each line. This would format it with a fixed size font. Or you can enclose it by the 
 preformat-tags `<pre>...</pre>` . 2) In what format is your data available? As text file, excel file, in a datbase table?

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44468018/4183191

Comment: I cant see the "realt time data" part yet....

Comment: Where are you getting this data from? Is it from a text file, some serial connection?

Comment: Do you maybe mean "time series" instead of real time data? I guess you have a given text file with the above format and a given number of records. If yes, it is data import from a file. If your source is for example a web server that does produce new data sets from time to time that you would like to read as they appear it would be real time data.