# Can GNU Octave handle dynamical plots for the GUI?

Tags: logging, arduino, octave, measure

I tested this [logging software](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/GNU-Octave-Logger) for Arduino and it works great, for a while.

The problem with this logging software is that the plot make the application freeze and I don't know why.

I have been testing the software for a while and it seems that the plot is the cause of the problem. It freeze and then the whole application freeze. It does not matter even if I plot with regular plot, or if I call an object of the plot and update its X, Y vectors.

https://github.com/DanielMartensson/GNU-Octave-Logger/blob/1c6001c115f402a6c3ec71c2ac95817666ea615b/export/wnd/GNU_Octave_Logger_thread.m#L98

```
% Focus on plot
axis(wnd.plot);
h = plot(rand(2));

[ code ]

set(h, {'YData'}, {analogInPlot; analogOutPlot});
set(h, {'XData'}, {L; L});
legend(h, 'Analog in', 'Analog out');
```

**So my question is:**

Even if I update the vectors, the plot can still freeze and then the whole application freeze as well. This is a combination with the GUI running.

Can it be that GNU Octave cannot handle dynamical plots for GUI? If I remove the plot, then the application works fine. So it must be that GNU Octave cannot handle dynamical plots for the GUI?

```
%set(h, {'YData'}, {analogInPlot; analogOutPlot});
%set(h, {'XData'}, {L; L});
%legend(h, 'Analog in', 'Analog out');
```

[image]

**Edit:**

- Operative system: Windows 11
- Octave Version: 7.2.0
- Packages included: arduino, instrument-control

Comment: can you add the Octave version, operating system, and any package versions used?

Comment: This might depend on the graphical backend used in Octave. https://wiki.octave.org/FAQ#Graphics:_backends_and_toolkits

Comment: @CrisLuengo i tried to change the backend from qt to gnuplot in GNU_Octave_Logger.def file, but it went very wrong for me

Comment: Do you all have an Arduino?

Comment: @CrisLuengo `fltk` and `gnuplot` won't work. I can't barely create an application with those.

Comment: I tried to add `disp('text...')` inside the never ending while loop. The logging software seems to work now. No stop yet.

Comment: Is the problem reproducible on Octave 6.x ?

Comment: @rahnema1 This is on 7.x. Can you run the script now? I think it works much better now.

Comment: I have seen somewhere a frozen plot on Octave 7.x. I want to ensure that it is only related to octave 7.x and no other factors.

Comment: To answer the more general point, plots in octave are dynamic by default. It's far more likely that whatever input you're passing to it "blocks" the system (e.g. waits for data to arrive from your arduino), until data arrives. Have you debugged your system to see if data is flowing as expected in the first place? Alternatively, it could be that you have multiple operations happening and the image needs to be 'flushed', e.g. with a `dranow` command. Alternatively, here's how to pass data through a socket if you want to try a different approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44468018/4183191